# Sum Selected Checkbox Values using PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I've been figuring out ways on how to work this out but I can't seem to. I'm a beginner in PHP and I'm so lost right now. I want to sum the selected checkboxes's values and post the sum of the values in a PHP page.

Here's my HTML so far

```html
<input class="wrapped-input" type="checkbox" value="290" id="widgetu15650_input" name="custom_U15293[]" tabindex="1"/>
<label for="widgetu15650_input"></label>
```

Here's my PHP so far

```php
if (isset($_POST['u15175'])) {
    if($_POST){
        $val = 0;
        foreach($_POST['custom_U15293'] as $custom_U15293){
            $val += $custom_U15293;
        }
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['custom_U15293']){
      $val = 0;
      foreach($_POST['custom_U15293'] as $custom_U15293){
      $val += (int) $custom_U15293;
    }
    echo $val;
  } else {
    echo 'Value not received';
  }
```

If you see `Value not received` there is some problem with your HTML code

Comment: Is it okay to use the if isset() and if($_POST) at the same time?

Comment: I find it right. try this `echo $_POST;` and see what it displays

Comment: Instead of echo $Val?

Comment: add it to the first line

Comment: Tried it, and nothing shows up whenever I click the button